# Checking a password meets a specific format in C

Tags: c

Im creating a password checker in C. The user enters their password and the program must check it fits the format `aa$B1BB$B$$aB` (where `a` represents lowercase, `B` uppercase, `$` symbol and `1` is a digit).

I have currently programmed an array of numbers `0` to `9`, symbols and letters and am trying to create a series of iterative loops to search each character of the password against the matching array of the criteria that it should meet. This was the easiest way I thought of but if anyone has any better suggestions it would be much appreciated.

The errors I am currently facing is that the program isn't running as I expected. If the password is not 13 characters long it should call the `else if` statement but it doesn't. So far I have only created statements for checking digits `1`, `2`, `3` and `4`. The `printf("Password ok #")` statements are just for testing purposes.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char password[20];
    int i, length;
    int numbers[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    char letters[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h',
                       'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p',
                       'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x',
                       'y', 'z' };
    char symbols[] = { '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', 
                       '-', '_', '+', '=' };

    printf("Password rules:\n"
           " --------------------- \n"
           " must follow the format ee$L1LL$L$$eL \n"
           " --------------------- \n"
           " Please enter your current password:");
    scanf("%c", password);
    printf("%19s", password);

    length = strlen(password);

    if (length = 13) {
        printf("Password ok 1");
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(letters); i++) {    
            if ((password[1] == letters[i]) && (password[2] == letters[i])) {
                printf("Password ok 2");
            } else {
                printf("Digits 1 or 2 do not fit the correct format");
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(symbols); i++) {
            if (password[3] == symbols[i]) {
                printf("Password ok 3");
            } else {
                printf("Digit 3 does not fit the correct format");
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(letters); i++) {
            if (password[4]==symbols[i]) {
                printf("Password ok 4");
            } else {
                printf("Digit 3 does not fit the correct format");
            }
        }
    } else if (length != 13) {
        printf("\nPassword must be 13 digits long");
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `if (length = 13)` to `if (length == 13)`.

Comment: Side note: `else if (length != 13)` -> `else` the `if (length != 13)` is useless.

Comment: In general, it is a really bad idea to enforce such a format. It is easily breakable. Looking at it as it is now, it looks like a simple bruteforce will break it in no time.

Comment: `scanf("%c", password);` -> `scanf("%s", password);`. Compiler with `-Wall`

Comment: @Eugene Sh. Im not so worried about security purposes, if thats what you're referring to when you mention that its easily breakable? I just need to ensure the program is able to check if a password meets the required format :)

Comment: @MaisieBrooke Well, but it has some practical application in the future I guess? If so, you should not enforce specific positional format. You want it to contain lowercase and uppercase letters along with numbers and special symbols? Fine, but do not enforce these to be at specific positions, because it does not make sense and is not secure.

Comment: Hint: decompose your program into smaller parts: using functions. You need a function that tests if a char is an uppercase letter, one that tests if a char is a lowercase letter one that tests if a char is a symbol etc. It's going to be much simpler.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I suppose it's just a programming exercise

Comment: I think your approach is wrong. If someone changes the format, you need to alter the code, and that doesn't make sense to me. Just parse the prescribed format as you go, and depending on the `n`th character, you pick a validation function.

Comment: Why not use a `switch()` on pattern-chars? You're not allowed to use library functions like `isupper()` & `isdigit()`?

Comment: @EugeneSh. This is a task assigned to me by my coding tutor and is not going to be used in any practical purposes, it's just for me to get used to C programming.  The only specification of the task is to ensure the password fits the chosen format :) But yes i understand that if this were to be implemented in a real application this would be a terrible idea as a hacker would find it easier to access

Comment: @Jabberwocky Even that should make sense... If they want to do such an exercise, they shouldn't call it "password"

Comment: @Jabberwocky that seems like a much better idea! I dont know why that slipped my mind, i think im going to try that. Thank you!

Comment: @EugeneSh. well you know that there are many, many bad C teachers out there, judging by some the type of questions we see here.

Comment: @MaisieBrooke also apply Cheatah's and SparKot's suggestions. You'll see, your code will be much simpler and cleaner and possibly even shorter than the code you show in the question. And you could check passwords agains any pattern like e.g. `aa$B1B` or `aa$B1BB$B$$B1BB$B$$aB` or anything else

Comment: @MaisieBrooke Certinaly `char letters[] = {'a','b','c','c','e','f','...` is a typo.  Did you want `char letters[] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','...`?

Comment: @MaisieBrooke also let us know if this is an academic exercise or a real workd problem.

Comment: @Jabberwocky yeah its just an exercise Ive been set by my coding tutor for learning purposes, its not to be applied to a real world problem. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: @MaisieBrooke Should input like `"aa$B1BB$B$$aB xyz\n"` pass?  IOWs, if the test needs to detect spaces on input, do not use `scanf("%s"...` to read a _line_ of user input.  Use `fgets()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're allowed to use `ctype` macros like `isupper()`, `islower()` then you can call them against every pattern-char as.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { // Enumerate codes used in the password-pattern
    eLower = 'a',
    eUpper = 'B',
    eDigit = '1',
    eSymbol = '$'
};

char* pp_errors[] = { // Error strings for pattern-mismatch
    "No Error",
    "Lower case letter expected",
    "Upper case letter expected",
    "Digit is expected",
    "Punctuation expected",
    "Pattern Not handled"
};

int
check_pattern_char (const unsigned char pwdC, const unsigned char patC)
{
    switch (patC) {
    case eLower : if (!islower (pwdC)) return 1;
        break;
    case eUpper : if (!isupper (pwdC)) return 2;
        break;
    case eDigit : if (!isdigit (pwdC)) return 3;
        break;
    case eSymbol : if (!ispunct (pwdC)) return 4;
        break;
    default: return 5; // pattern not handled
    }
    return 0;
}

int main ()
{
    char password [128];
    char pattern [] = "aa$B1BB$B$$aB";
    int ptlen = strlen (pattern);

    printf ("Enter a password that follows pattern [%s]: ", pattern);
    while (1 != scanf ("%127s", password));
    if ( (int) strlen (password) != ptlen) {
        printf ("\nPassword must be [%d] chars long.\n", ptlen);
        return 1;
    }
    for (int pi = 0; pi < ptlen; ++pi) {
        int status;
        if ( (status = check_pattern_char (password[pi], pattern[pi]))) {
            printf ("\nERROR: [%s] at pos[%d] [%c][%c]\n",
                    pp_errors[status], pi + 1, pattern[pi], password[pi]);
            return 2;
        }
    }
    printf ("\nPassword [%s] accepted against Pattern[%s]\n", password, pattern);
    return 0;
}
```

Or you can write your own functions for them like :

```c
static inline int my_islower (const char ch) {
    return (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z');
}
static inline int my_isupper (const char ch) {
    return (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z');
}
static inline int my_isdigit (const char ch) {
    return (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9');
}
static inline int my_ispunct (const char ch) {
    // allowed punctuations
    char puncts[] = "!@#$%^&*-_+=";
    for (char* pp = puncts; *pp; )
        if (*pp++ == ch) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

`static inline` is telling compiler that this function is local to this `translation-unit`(current file) & requesting it to inline function if possible at the calling location. This mitigates the overheads of calling small functions.

Answer (score 1):

To check if the password fits

```
format aa$B1BB$B$$aB
```

Use `fgets()` to read, `sscanf()` to scan and `"%n"` to detect scanning end.

```
// scanf("%c",password); // %c only reads 1 character
// printf("%19s",password);

if (fgets(password, sizeof password, stdin)) {
  password[strcspn(password, "\n")] = '\0'; // Lop off potential \n
  printf("<%s>\n", password);
  int n = 0; 
  // format aa$B1BB$B$$aB
  #define FMT_a "%*1[a-z]"
  #define FMT_B "%*1[A-Z]"
  #define FMT_1 "%*1[0-9]"
  #define FMT_S "%*1[-!@#$%^&*_+=]"  // '-' first
  sscanf(password, 
      FMT_a FMT_a FMT_S FMT_B FMT_1 FMT_B FMT_B FMT_S FMT_B FMT_S FMT_S FMT_a FMT_B "%n",
      &n);
  bool Success = n > 0 && password[n] == '\0';
```

---

A more robust approach uses a series of `strchr()` calls in case letters [a-z] are not consecutive.

---

IMO, use a more generous read buffer.

```
// char password[20];
char password[100];
```

Comment: I suppose the goal here is hand coding the function and not to rely on advanced `scanf` usage

Comment: @Jabberwocky Perhaps.  I never quite agree with assignments that imply "solve without using some part of C".

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thank you for your answer! Would you mind explaining to me the last line of code? What is the `bool success` variable set to and how does it work? I want to use this to display if the password is accepted or not? :)

Comment: If scanning `password` never made it to the end, `n` is never set and remains 0.  If scanning succeeded all the way to `"%n"`, then `n` is set to the scan offset at that point.  If the password had extra junk at the end then `password[n] == '\0'` would be false.  Research `fscanf()` and `%n` for scan details.  If you are not familiar with `bool`, research any good C  book.

Answer (score 0):

**Below code is perfect by using ctype.h**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool valid(const char *password);

int main(void)
{
    char password[] = "Password@123";
    if (valid(password))
    {
        printf("Your password is valid!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Your password needs at least one uppercase letter, lowercase letter, number and symbol\n");
    }
}

// TODO: Complete the Boolean function below
bool valid(const char *password)
{
    int length = strlen(password);
    int lower_count = 0;
    int upper_count = 0;
    int digit_count = 0;
    int symbol_count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        if(islower(password[i])){
         lower_count += 1;
    }
        if(isupper(password[i])){
             upper_count += 1;
        }
        if(isdigit(password[i])){
             digit_count += 1;
        }
        if(ispunct(password[i])){
            symbol_count += 1;
        }
    }

printf("Lower Count: %d\nUpper Count: %d\nDigit Count: %d\nSymbol Count: %d\n", lower_count, upper_count, digit_count, symbol_count);
    if(lower_count != 0 && upper_count != 0 && digit_count != 0 && symbol_count != 0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Output is:**

> Lower Count: 7
>
> Upper Count: 1
>
> Digit Count: 3
>
> Symbol Count: 1
>
> Your password is valid!

Comment: You could actually remove all those `if ...` tests in the loop and just use code like `lower_count += !!islower(password[i]);`. The double-pling will make anything non-zero into a `1` and keep zeros intact.